# Intercepting a moving target with limited change in velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have an already moving object A trying to intercept a moving target B in 3D space, and I have limited acceleration (for example not necessarily enough fuel for the optimal acceleration).

[image]

A is located at A0 in the image at time t0, and is currently traveling with a velocity va. B is located at B0, and is traveling with a velocity vb. I can do an instant acceleration *a* at t0 applied to object A, as long as the magnitude of *a* is less than a maximum M. I can't change the trajectory of B. At time t1,  A will be located at A1 (after I accelerate), and B will be located at B1.

Obviously this may, or may not, be enough to put the two objects on an interception path (despite the acceleration, the initial velocity could not be feasibly overcome, so the two objects could forever move further apart). Instead I want to get as close as possible at a later time t1.

At time t1, I want to minimize the distance *d* between the two objects (between A1 and B1) as much as possible without exceeding M in acceleration. I can only accelerate once, at t0.

We know the value of every variable mentioned except the acceleration vector *a*, which we have to solve, and A1 (which can be derived once we know *a*).

---

So the task is this: out of all possible solutions for the value of *a* (I don't know if there is more than one) which minimize *d*, find the smallest *a* (say I want to conserve fuel, so accelerate as least as possible). Not just the magnitude of *a*, the whole vector so I know in which direction to accelerate.

---

I've looked at a few similar questions, but they didn't quite match my particular restrictions, or at least if they did, I'm not smart enough in physics to know how to apply those solutions to my case. Sorry if this has been asked before.

No particular urgency for receiving an answer. If it's like within the next 6 months, that's ok with me. I'm just developing a video game, and I can postpone this particular implementation for quite some time. Approximate solutions are also acceptable, if it's easier to solve/calculate that way.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: on close inspection, I need to clarify that we also don't already know the value of *d*, it's not pre-determined. But we can derive it after we know *a*, just like A1. So if my vector math is not wrong, A1 = A0 + (va + a) * (t1 - t0). And d is just Pythagoras with A1 and B1. Neither A1 or d are independent variables, they can just be expressed as functions of *a* and the other fixed values. Also worth clarifying that t1 is not an independent variable either, it's just a given constant, which simplifies the problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't make too much sense and there are too many variables in play. The initial velocities, the separation, the initial positions and it would become very tedious. You want the acceleration a to be as least as possible at a given time to conserve fuel but you want the object to get as close as possible to the other object which is only possible at the maximum acceleration in most cases.

Comment: If it doesn't make too much sense, maybe I haven't communicated clearly enough. I can provide additional info if needed. As for variables, there is a single variable in play, the acceleration, the rest are predetermined constant values, I'm not sure what you mean by too many variables. As close as possible doesn't mean a distance of 0. Similarly for acceleration. If the acceleration is at the maximum allowed, that's an acceptable result, as long no better solution exists.

Comment: the initial positions, the velocities they all might be predetermined in your game and you can directly plug in the values. but right here, the positions and velocities are considered as variables since we don't know their exact values and directions.

Comment: I have just done it roughly on paper and got a large equation that wraps around half my page with 8 variables(position coordinates, velocities and acceleration and the angle they make with the x axis) that gives the distance. Now I have to differentiate it twice w.r.t time and acceleration each that I have assumed to be variables to find the global minima of the function.

Comment: now here, i have just assumed the entire thing to be in a 2d plane and you will have 14 variables in case you are doing it in 3D and that could be tedious even for the machine that you are running the game to calculate and might cause lag spikes. Try using some other algorithms rather than predicting the path like this.

Comment: Ouch. I was afraid of something like that. I know that theoretically it can be solved by expressing d as a function of a (which gives us a 4D function because of the 3D nature of a) then finding the local minimum. When I posted this I was hoping someone had a better idea, or maybe it was already solved.

Comment: Your question is very particular. it was near impossible that someone already had the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've given a few thoughts to this problem since I first posted it, and *I think* I may have found a solution. But I'm not 100% sure, so I would really appreciate it if someone double checks it.

---

So we know that:

$A1 = A0 + (va + a) * (t1 - t0)$

$B1 = B0 + vb * (t1 - t0)$

---

I am going to define $T = t1 - t0$

$A1 = A0 + (va + a) * T$

$B1 = B0 + vb * T$

---

Breaking it into equations for x, y, z respectively:

$A1_x = A0_x  + (va_x + a_x) * T$

$A1_y = A0_y  + (va_y + a_y) * T$

$A1_z = A0_z  + (va_z + a_z) * T$

$B1_x = B0_x + vb_x * T$

$B1_y = B0_y + vb_y * T$

$B1_z = B0_z + vb_z * T$

$d = \sqrt {(A1_x - B1_x) ^ 2 + (A1_y - B1_y) ^ 2 + (A1_z - B1_z) ^ 2} $

---

d is what we are trying to minimize.

$f(a_x, a_y, a_z) = d = \sqrt {(A0_x  + (va_x + a_x) * T - B1_x)^2 + (A0_y  + (va_y + a_y) * T - B1_y) ^ 2 + (A0_z  + (va_z + a_z) * T - B1_z) ^ 2}$

$f(a_x, a_y, a_z) = d = \sqrt {(A0_x  + va_x * T + a_x * T - B1_x) ^ 2 + (A0_y  + va_y * T + a_y * T - B1_y) ^ 2 + (A0_z  + va_z * T + a_z * T - B1_z) ^ 2}$

---

I'm going to define some constants:

$K_x = A0_x  + va_x * T - B1_x$

$K_y = A0_y  + va_y * T - B1_y$

$K_z = A0_z  + va_z * T - B1_z$

---

$f(a_x, a_y, a_z) = d = \sqrt {(K_x + a_x * T) ^ 2 + (K_y + a_y * T) ^ 2 + (K_z + a_z * T) ^ 2}$

Now, ideally we want d = 0, we can't hope for a more closer approach than a distance of 0 (there is still M to consider, but we'll get to that). So I can try to solve that equation. Each term, like $(K_x + a_x * T) ^ 2$ is always >= 0. The only way d = 0, is if all the terms inside the square root are also 0.

$(K_x + a_x * T) ^ 2 = 0$

$K_x + a_x * T = 0$

$a_x = - K_x / T$

$a_y = - K_y / T$

$a_z = - K_z / T$

Interesting observation: there is a singular solution to this equation for real numbers. Now let us consider M. The vector length of *a* needs to be less than M. If we calculate the value of *a* using the above formula, and its length is <= M, then that is the singular optimal solution to our problem and we are done. Otherwise, that is not a valid solution at all.

---

Here comes the part where I am not 100% sure of, because I don't have the math skills to prove it right now. Let us go back to the $f(a_x, a_y, a_z) = d$ equation. Interestingly, that is the equation of the euclidean distance (edit: with a linear distortion T, but that doesn't matter) of each point in 3D to a center point = $(K_x, K_y, K_z)$. If I am not mistaken (and I might be, this is the first time in my life working with 4 dimensions), that is a 4D cone (hypercone). To make it easier to work with, I've gone and reduced the number of dimensions for illustrative purposes. Here is an image:

[image]

The black circle is the |a| <= M circle, centered around 0, 0 with radius M. The yellow-blue gradient is the regular 3D cone equivalent, with the tip at the yellowest point. That tip is the solution to the previous equation when d = 0. It's a valid solution if it's within the black circle, otherwise the point is outside. If that's the case, then we can draw the dotted line that connects (0, 0) to the cone tip. That line intersects the black circle at distance M. If I am not mistaken that point is the closest to the cone tip and it's the solution to our problem. To calculate it, we just take the previous value of *a* that we calculated, and reduce the length to match M without changing direction. And I think the same logic applies in 4D.

I would appreciate it if someone verifies my calculations and logic here. Thank you.